# view folder path confusion after overriding using Theme method

Tags: magento2

When i override the phtml using my custom theme in Magento 2, should i have to keep the view folder in the Module.

ie) **view/frontend/templates** and 
    **view/frontend/layout**
folder?

If i have to keep the layout xml inside the view/layout folder, should it be inside view/.. or what is the correct path?

**UPDATED QUESTION**:

After keeping my template in the template folder and xml in the layout folder of my theme.

Whats the content of the xml here :  Vendor_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml

Is it the my custom **vendor_Catalog** name or **Magento_Catalog:: ...**

```
<referenceBlock class="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" >
      <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml</argument>
      </action>
    </referenceBlock>
```

Comment: at which place want to keep file inside theme or your custom module?

Comment: inside my custom theme..sorry i dint mention that...

Comment: please check my answer

Comment: you have to give Magento_Catalog instead of your custom module name, if you have overrride file inside your custom module/extension then you have to give your custom module path

Comment: I got confused...Can u give eg for what yu mean by  "if you have overrride file inside your custom module/extension then you have to give your custom module path"

Comment: If you have create module and keep phtml file inside module then you have to keep vendor_modulename

Comment: Means Custom module with new (Custom phtml file) rite which is not overidden from Magento ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When i override the phtml using my custom theme in Magento 2, should i
>   have to keep the view folder in the Module.

**If you have keep phtml file inside your custom theme, You doesn't need to keep view folder inside module.**

If you want to override your core template file or core layout file into your custom theme, Path for that is below,

**For override into your custom theme, you not need to declare view folder**

Lets take example from Catalog module of core

For layout override,

> magento2/app/design/frontend/Vendorname/themename/Magento_Catalog/layout

For Templates override,

> magento2/app/design/frontend/Vendorname/themename/Magento_Catalog/templates

Thanks.

Comment: Please see my updated question!!